# Adding custom right click menu to the nodes of treeview in MVC

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, treeview

This is my helper for generating a treeview.
Using this i am able to generate the treeview in the mvc5.

```
@helper GetTreeView(List<MvcTreeview.Models.Category> siteMenu, int parentID)
{
foreach (var i in siteMenu.Where(a => a.ParentID.Equals(parentID)))
{
    <li>
        @{var submenu = siteMenu.Where(a => a.ParentID.Equals(i.ID)).Count();}
        @if (submenu > 0)
        {
            <span class="collapse collapsible">&nbsp;</span>
        }
        else
        {
            <span style="width:15px; display:inline-block">&nbsp;</span>
        }
        <span id="Category">
            <a href="#" onclick="PassingFunction(@i.ID)">@i.CategoryName</a>
            @*oncontextmenu="return false"*@
        </span>

        @if (submenu > 0)
        {
            <ul>
                @Treeview.GetTreeView(siteMenu, i.ID)
                @* Recursive  Call for Populate Sub items here*@
            </ul>
        }
    </li>
}
}
```

This is my View for displaying

```
    @model List<MvcTreeview.Models.Category>
    @{
    ViewBag.Title = "Simple";
    }

    <div class="gridbox gridleft">
    <div class="left">
        <div style="padding:10px; background-color:#FAFAFA">
            <div class="treeview">
                @if (Model != null && Model.Count() > 0)
                {
                    <ul>
                        @Treeview.GetTreeView(Model, Model.FirstOrDefault().ParentID)
                    </ul>
                }
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div id="onSuccess">
</div>
    @* Here We need some Jquery code for make this treeview collapsible *@
    @section Scripts{
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $(".treeview li>ul").css('display', 'none'); // Hide all 2-level ul
            $(".collapsible").click(function (e) {
                e.preventDefault();
                $(this).toggleClass("collapse expand");
                $(this).closest('li').children('ul').slideToggle();
            });
        });



        function PassingFunction(clicked_id) {
            url = '@Url.Action("Details", "TestDetails")';
            $.ajax({
                url: url,
                type: 'GET',
                data: { 'id': clicked_id },
                success: function (returnData) {
                    $("#onSuccess").html(returnData);
                    console.log(returnData);

                },
                error: {
                }
            });
        }



    </script>
    }
```

Now i want to add the custom functionalities to the nodes of the treeview

1. Add
2. Delete
3. Edit

How can i do that?

Answer (score 2):

There is a lot of [JQuery Context Menu options on this link](https://plugins.jquery.com/tag/context-menu/).

I have just picked the most forked of them, [jQuery contextMenu](http://swisnl.github.io/jQuery-contextMenu/demo.html).

I created a JSFeed fork in an example of treeview using UL/LI and created this JSFiddle with the Context-Menu to help you:
http://jsfiddle.net/mqueirozcorreia/0h82qto6/

---

**Explaining the code:**

I have added the externals resources:

```
http://swisnl.github.io/jQuery-contextMenu/dist/jquery.contextMenu.min.css

https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js

http://swisnl.github.io/jQuery-contextMenu/dist/jquery.contextMenu.min.js
```

All the magic goes in the javascript code, configuring the context-menu.

The selector property will put the context menu in every element of type `<span>` and having class attribute with value "contextMenuItem":

```
selector: 'span.contextMenuItem',
```

When the user clicks the callback function below runs. In this example, it alerts/logs what key was selected and the id attribute value.

```
callback: function(key, options) {
  var m = "clicked: " + key + " on element of id " + options.$trigger.attr("id");
  window.console && console.log(m) || alert(m); 
},
```